# Solr DIH Mysql configuration

Tags: mysql, solr, configuration, import, dih

```
<entity name="tw_tweet_user_merged" query="select * from tw_tweet_user_merged">
    <field column="id" name="id" />
    <field column="gender" name="gender" />
    <entity name="tw_flag" query="select moderator_id from tw_flag where tweet_id='${tw_tweet_user_merged.id}'">
        <field column="moderator_id" name="moderator_id" />
    </entity>
</entity>
```

This is my DIH data-config.xml,
It is importing id, user_id but not uid, 
flagged_by in schema.xml is

```
<field name="moderator_id" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you have column and name reversed in your  config.

You can also get rid of the field config and do the name changing in the SQL:

select uid as flagged_by from flag where tweet_id='${tweets.id}'

Answer (score 0):

don't know why, but

```
<entity name="tw_tweet_user_merged" query="select * from tw_tweet_user_merged">
    <field column="id" name="id" />
    <field column="gender" name="gender" />
    <entity name="tw_flag" query="select moderator_id as flagged from tw_flag where tweet_id='${tw_tweet_user_merged.id}'">
        <field column="moderator_id" name="moderator_id" />
    </entity>
</entity>
```

work for me. Just adding "**as someColName**" in sub query